# Bootstrap heading on iPhone not resizing properly

Tags: html, ios, iphone, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Using this code, using bootstrap:

```
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="display-2 text-black text-left">Small Business Marketing</h1>
    <h2 class="display-5 text-black text-left">Free Consultation. Affordable Help.</h2>
    <a class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg float-left" href="services.html" role="button">Find out more.</a>
</div>
```

Everything works great, except on small iPhones. On the iPhone about 15 pixels of the"marketing" in h1 is being chopped off to the right. It also creates some awkward page toggling and blank space because of the text overflow. It's as if the container is not staying within the screen size because it is being enlarged by the text.

I have a temporary fix  by wrapping the h1 with a row class:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h1 class="display-2 text-white text-left">Small Business Marketing</h1>
    </div>
    <h2 class="display-5 text-white text-left">Free Consultation. Affordable Help.</h2>
    <a class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg float-left" href="services.html" role="button">Find out more.</a>
</div>
```

This works but now the heading really kisses the left side and doesn't look quite right. I feel like the ideal solution is a smaller responsive font-size that I was expecting the bootstrap responsiveness to take care of. 
One reason this will continue to be a problem is adding one more letter to Marketing ie Marketingg, the second g completely disappears.

I have my viewport setting proper according to      https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

Edit: intro first line adding bootstrap

Comment: can you show your custom css, there are classes in your code which are not bootstrap css, so we have no idea what they are doing

Comment: Which class isn't bootstrap? My css is all from here: github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-one-page-wonder see folder vendor>css>bootstrap.css and css>one-page-wonder.css

Comment: display-2 seems to be the one causing you issues

Comment: Sure, but I like the styling. It is a bootstrap style https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/typography/#display-headings ...so I still expect it to be responsive. Can you suggest css overrides that might be useful? I haven't found any.